# Downloadbutton in a Treetable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I got a Treetable with **Primefaces 5.2** and want to add a download button, this button works fine when its out of the Treetable (with selected nodes) but in the Treetable the button isn't working and I can't find the mistake

```
<p:treeTable id="docs" value="#{ttContextMenuView.root}"
        var="document" selectionMode="single"
        selection="#{ttContextMenuView.selectedNode}">
        <f:facet name="header">
        Document Viewer
    </f:facet>
        <p:column headerText="Name">
            <h:outputText value="#{document.name}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Size">
            <h:outputText value="#{document.size}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Type">
            <h:outputText value="#{document.type}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Path">
            <h:outputText value="#{document.path}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Downlaad">
            <p:commandButton value="Download" ajax="false"
                icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s"
                rendered="#{document.type ne 'Folder'}">
                <p:fileDownload value="#{fileDownloadView.file(document.path)}" />
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:column>
    </p:treeTable>
```

Thanks.

Comment: To avoid the obvious, what scope is bean put in? Aren't you doing anything else in the getter method of `root` other than merely returning the already-prepared model?

Comment: @BalusC the Bean is put in SessionScoped and yes in the getter i am only returning the prepared tree, heres the code 
"public TreeNode getRoot() {
        return root;
    }"